# fixed-fluid-fixed layout

Tags: css, multiple-columns, dynamic-columns

I'm trying to create a three column layout in CSS only with fixed left and right columns and a fluid central column. I have searched online but nothing has worked when I implement it. I don't know whether this is particularly relevant but my central column is (or contains, I've tried both) an iframe. This seems to be contributing to the complication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using an 960 grid ?

- http://960.gs/

Otherwise there are many examples for using fixed and fluid grid layouts in the web:

- http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/perfect-3-column.htm
- http://www.dynamicdrive.com/style/layouts/item/css-liquid-layout-31-fixed-fluid-fixed/
  This is the one you are looking for.

Btw: Please provide some of your code, or do a jsfiddle about it !

Comment: 960 grid system would require a fixed-fixed-fixed column-width layout. The matthewjamestaylor link is about a fluid-fluid-fluid layout. I am looking for a fixed-fluid-fixed layout.

Comment: @GabrielG In the Mather James Taylor's website that EvilP linked, in the upper right corner click `Measure columns in: Pixel widths`

Comment: @kolin yeah its a really good resource. you could also visit bootstrap from twitter.